# how to add program to menu that is not in usr/share

Tags: 20.04, launcher, menu

Using Ubuntu 20.04 -  I 'installed' a program (for Ubuntu) by extracting from a tar file (apparently the only way to 'install' it) to its own folder on the desktop, and it has a launcher shortcut within that folder which points to an executable text file (also within the desktop folder). Both the launcher and the executable work as expected, but I do not want this folder cluttering my desktop. I have looked at other similar questions and answers but none of those resolved my problem, although some addressed the same/similar issue.

Question 1:  How can I move the program folder to where it SHOULD be located instead of on the desktop without breaking anything? Tried moving it to usr/share/ (where all other apps appear to be) - "permission denied". (Do I need root privelege? How do I get that?)

Question 2: Once it is in the right place, how do I get it into the main menu so I do not have to go looking for it deep inside the system when I want to use it?

Need plain english instructions, designed for a novice user. Terminal commands to effect a solution are OK as long as instructions are simple and absolutely complete, no assumptions about anything. Novice User.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
sudo nautilus  -q
```

open file manager, right click in empty erea open as administrator move your app folder to `user/bin/`  copy xxx.desktop to `user/share/applications` or move the app folder to `home/yourusernam/.local/bin` and copy xxx.desktop to `home/yourusernam/.local/share/applications`

you can add shortcut to desktop by make a link from xxx.desktop and move the link to desktop, you can add the shortcut to dock by searsh on the app name in app menu or activities,right click and choose add to favorites.

Comment: tried your instructions. Nautilus installed but when entered second command :      sudo nautilus -q        I got error message:  
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4403): WARNING **: 14:20:09.354: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Tracker1 was not provided by any .service files
barbara@barbara-HP-EliteBook-850-G2:~$

Comment: reopen file manager to find open as administrator  in right click menu

Comment: In spite of the error noted in my first comment above, Opening file manager as administrator (? root) allowed me to move the folder and copy the xxx.desktop file as instructed but it still does not appear in the menu, and the link remains broken.  How do I make a new link or repair the broken link?  And how do I get the app to appear in the menu?

Comment: after moving the app folder to new place, create link https://askubuntu.com/questions/941706/create-link-to-file-on-desktop-or-in-folder

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/add-application-shortcuts-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Finally, it is working as it should. Developers should include install instructions if their program installer does not behave in the standard manner, and not just assume that the user can work it out.

Comment: @BJHPNG good news, can you accept my answer please